# Save workspace in Unity Ubuntu 16.04

Tags: unity, workspaces

If I have certain applications open and each window positioned and sized in a certain way, can I save then? Also can I lock then to these positions?

Ideally I would make icon shortcuts for those views so once I turn on my computer I can select between a workspace for Web Development, Drawing + listening to music, Writing.

Comment: Your question mentions two separate goals, which are answered in two earlier questions (by others):  http://askubuntu.com/questions/631392/saving-and-restoring-window-positions/631467#631467 and http://askubuntu.com/questions/613973/how-can-i-start-up-an-application-with-a-pre-defined-window-size-and-position/614205#614205 please mention if you manage. You might also like http://www.webupd8.org/2016/03/how-to-save-and-restore-unity-session.html

Comment: Possible duplicate of: https://askubuntu.com/questions/71018/save-workspace-between-boots-on-linux/117405#117405  (the answer you accepted was a direct theft of this linked answer/question)